# Redefine global variable after async forEach loop is executed

Tags: javascript

I'm going back and forth on StackOverflow trying to find this specific answer, but I can't find anything that works. "Test" should be defined after the execution of the async function inside the loop. If I try to console log "Test" it returns undefined. How can I wait for the loop execution to proceed in the stack?

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let test;   

array.forEach(async el => {  
  await setTimeout(() => {
    if(el === 5) {
      test = true      
    }
  }, 5000)
})

console.log(test)
```

I also tried defining an async function with the loop into it and then calling an IIFE, awaiting for the function and console logging the variable. It returns the same undefined.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let test;   

async function hey() {
    array.forEach(async el => {  
  await setTimeout(() => {
    if(el === 5) {
      test = true      
    }
  }, 5000)
})
}

(async () => {
  await hey();
  console.log(test);  
})()
```

Comment: My answer is not the correct one. Seems like it's not working as it should. Please 'unaccept' it so i can delete it :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise from your async function. Otherwise you cannot ' await '.
Not really sure what you are trying to do inside that foreach loop.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let test;

async function hey() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    array.forEach( el => {


      setTimeout(function() {
        el === 5 ? resolve(true) : resolve(false)

      }, 5000);

    })
  })
}

(async () => {
  test = await hey();
  console.log(test);
})()
```

Comment: I added the false by mistake. But it's working once I promisify the forEach loop. Thx

Comment: Hmm i have second thoughts about my answer. I will check it some more. Please make sure it's working correctly in your application